# Automatically detect client sessions mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I realized after developing a bit that mongodb's java driver requires you to specify the ClientSession for every action. Is there a way to make it automatically use the one currently on the thread or something, or do I have to manually specify it everywhere?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question with a code snippet please ? The use of `ClientSession` in most cases would be transparent.

Comment: Really? If you did: try(ClientSession session = createSession()) { col.insertOne(thing); } it would work?

Comment: I see what you mean. Currently you would have to specify it on the operation `try (ClientSession clientSession = client.startSession()) { col.insertOne(clientSession, thing); ... `. Just to clarify, do you need the session for specific use case? i.e. consistency or transactions. etc.

Comment: I want it to make it so if something goes wrong, e.g. exception being thrown, changes rollback

Comment: I see, what you're looking for is [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) then. You would need to use `Session` to utilise transaction. However, not all sessions are for transactions.

Comment: That's what I'm using, but I was trying to find a way to make it so I don't need to pass the transaction session to every method. But its not really absolutely necessary I guess, I just didn't use transactions for everything, only important things.